# Android videoview mediacontroller pause or play button

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, mediacontroller

My video works fine but i cant controll it. I cant see play or pause button.i need play or pause button .mediaController not working fine. i using this codes

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class avid extends Activity
{
    private String path = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4";
    private VideoView video_view_;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.avid);
        video_view_ = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        MediaController mediaController=new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(video_view_);
        video_view_.setMediaController(mediaController);
        video_view_.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
        video_view_.start();
    }
}
```

layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

i see only video . i need play or pause button 
here is picture [enter link description here](http://postimg.org/image/swrls48yt/c7f587a6/)

Comment: Your code is working perfectly fine. Do recheck..!!

Answer (score 0):

you can put the media controller directly in the main xml file like this :

```
<MediaController
        android:id="@+id/mediaController1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

and normaly, when the video start, you can see the media controller.