# Android video playback issues

Tags: android

I have bit of trouble playing back video in my app. I have the very similar code as below playing back my audio files, however, when I try to play video I'm not seeing a picture, I can still hear the narration but no video. Just to exclude encoding, I dropped in my assets a file from my cell that was created on my cell and I was trying to play it back using the above method without luck. Any thoughts would be appreciated, Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout        
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_audio_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<VideoView
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/fragmentVidListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ListView>
```

```
public class MediaPlayer extends AppCompatActivity implements OnPreparedListener, MediaController.MediaPlayerControl {

private static final String TAG = "VideoPlayer";
private android.media.MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private MediaController mediaController;
private String videoFileName= "test2.mp4";
private Handler handler = new Handler();


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_video_view);

    mediaPlayer = new android.media.MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

    mediaController = new MediaController(this);

    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = MediaPlayer.this.getAssets().openFd(videoFileName);
        long start = descriptor.getStartOffset();
        long end = descriptor.getLength();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), start, end);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not open file " + videoFileName + " for playback.", e);
    }

}

@Override
public void onPrepared(android.media.MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared");
    mediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.videoView1));

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mediaController.setEnabled(true);
            mediaController.show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mediaController.hide();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { //the MediaController will hide after 3 seconds - tap the screen to make it appear again
    mediaController.show();
    return false;
}

public void start() {
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

public void pause() {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
}

public int getDuration() {
    return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
}

public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
}

public void seekTo(int i) {
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
}

public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
}

public int getBufferPercentage() {
    return 0;
}

public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
}

public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return true;
}

public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getAudioSessionId() {
    return 0;
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}
}
```

Comment: You added a videoView but you are using a separate mediaPlayer? Set the datasource on the videoview and prepare the videoView instead of the mediaplayer.

Comment: if you want the video to be played in VideoView, then you should use it as MediaPlayer. Don't use separate MediaPlayer

Comment: I tried two different approaches, I used the VideoView alone, it kind of worked the video was distorted to fit the VideoView, probably a separate issue. So I started playing with the MediaPlayer, first in hope that this somehow would maintain an aspect ratio of my videoView and also would provide buttons to pause and control the video playback,  the VideoView doesn't seem to be doing that by itself

Comment: I found an item on the site that helped me linking Webview to MediaPlayer that works great http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151529/android-videoview-mediacontroller-pause-or-play-button